# Getting JSON data from API as array or object

Tags: php, json, api

I am using sports-radar API to get the schedule of NFL week 1. The API returns the following data in `json` format (I shortened string for example).

```
"id": "8e45fe2d-fb95-4504-845d-7c815623ccd6",
    "year": 2018,
    "type": "REG",
    "name": "REG",
    "week": {
        "id": "37435167-5cf6-4cce-b405-ff0e264ced9c",
        "sequence": 1,
        "title": "1",
        "games": [{
    "id": "0822b924-eadc-4398-bfe6-83cbbf3a2912",
            "status": "scheduled",
            "reference": "57570",
            "number": 4,
            "scheduled": "2018-09-09T17:00:00+00:00",
            "entry_mode": "INGEST",
            "venue": {
        "id": "6ed18563-53e0-46c2-a91d-12d73a16456d",
                "name": "Lucas Oil Stadium",
                "city": "Indianapolis",
                "state": "IN",
                "country": "USA",
                "zip": "46225",
                "address": "500 South Capitol Avenue",
                "capacity": 67000,
                "surface": "artificial",
                "roof_type": "retractable_dome"
            },
            "home": {
        "id": "82cf9565-6eb9-4f01-bdbd-5aa0d472fcd9",
                "name": "Indianapolis Colts",
                "alias": "IND",
                "game_number": 1
            },
            "away": {
        "id": "ad4ae08f-d808-42d5-a1e6-e9bc4e34d123",
                "name": "Cincinnati Bengals",
                "alias": "CIN",
                "game_number": 1
            },
            "broadcast": {
        "network": "CBS"
            }
        }, {
    "id": "0a456149-c547-4856-9b1b-86e1d93887ae",
            "status": "scheduled",
            "reference": "57574",
            "number": 8,
            "scheduled": "2018-09-09T17:00:00+00:00",
            "entry_mode": "INGEST",
            "venue": {
        "id": "3c85d89a-ec66-4983-acd5-1381d6c8673a",
                "name": "Mercedes-Benz Superdome",
                "city": "New Orleans",
                "state": "LA",
                "country": "USA",
                "zip": "70112",
                "address": "1500 Sugar Bowl Drive",
                "capacity": 73208,
                "surface": "artificial",
                "roof_type": "dome"
            },
            "home": {
        "id": "0d855753-ea21-4953-89f9-0e20aff9eb73",
                "name": "New Orleans Saints",
                "alias": "NO",
                "game_number": 1
            },
            "away": {
        "id": "4254d319-1bc7-4f81-b4ab-b5e6f3402b69",
                "name": "Tampa Bay Buccaneers",
                "alias": "TB",
                "game_number": 1
            },
            "broadcast": {
        "network": "FOX"
```

[I used the following website](https://jonsuh.com/blog/convert-loop-through-json-php-javascript-arrays-objects/) as a tutorial on how to display only the the data I need and how to loop over it

Note the JSON string is stored in the variable `$schedule`

**MY Code**

```
   // JSON string
      $jsonData = $schedule; //get json string

      // Convert JSON string to Array
      $jsonArray = json_decode($jsonData, true);


      // Convert JSON string to Object
      $jsonObject = json_decode($schedule);
```

**Looping through PHP Array or Object**

```
$someArray = $jsonArray
  foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["home"] . ", " . $value["away"] . "<br>";
  }

  // Loop through Object
  $someObject = jsonObject
  foreach($someObject as $key => $value) {
    echo $value->home . ", " . $value->away . "<br>";
  }
```

**My ERRORS**

When trying to convert the string to an array and attempting to get the `away` team name  I get the error **Illegal string offset** 'away' same problem with `home` and all other data

When trying to access data as an object I get the following error `Trying to get property of non-object`

I followed the tutorial to the letter. Yet im getting the basic errors above...? Any help and explanation would be appreciated. Thank you

EDIT:

`var_export($schedule)` returns the following:

```
array ( 'id' => '8e45fe2d-fb95-4504-845d-7c815623ccd6', 'year' => 2018, 'type' => 'REG', 'name' => 'REG', 'week' => array ( 'id' => '37435167-5cf6-4cce-b405-ff0e264ced9c', 'sequence' => 1, 'title' => '1', 'games' => array ( 0 => array ( 'id' => '0822b924-eadc-4398-bfe6-83cbbf3a2912', 'status' => 'scheduled', 'reference' => '57570', 'number' => 4, 'scheduled' => '2018-09-09T17:00:00+00:00', 'entry_mode' => 'INGEST', 'venue' => array ( 'id' => '6ed18563-53e0-46c2-a91d-12d73a16456d', 'name' => 'Lucas Oil Stadium', 'city' => 'Indianapolis', 'state' => 'IN', 'country' => 'USA', 'zip' => '46225', 'address' => '500 South Capitol Avenue', 'capacity' => 67000, 'surface' => 'artificial', 'roof_type' => 'retractable_dome', ), 'home' => array ( 'id' => '82cf9565-6eb9-4f01-bdbd-5aa0d472fcd9', 'name' => 'Indianapolis Colts', 'alias' => 'IND', 'game_number' => 1, ),
```

Comment: Only do this `$schedule = json_decode($jsonData, true);` and now check `var_export($schedule);` to check that at what index `away` is present and then try to adjust `foreach()` code

Comment: Ok give me a second to check and ill get back to you. Thank you

Comment: Do a `var_dump($someArray)`... Let's see what you've got.

Comment: You can't convert $value->home and $value->away to string as both are object.

Comment: your code has   `$someObject = jsonObject` correct it to
  `$someObject = $jsonObject`

Comment: Sorry that was a typo

Comment: @ChukwuemekaInya please see EDIT data with `var_dump / var_export` (string shortened)

Comment: So `$schedule` is array or string?

Comment: @DavidWinder it contains the JSON data returned from the API

Comment: In your code you wrote in the comment that `$schedule` is `//get json string` but as your `var_export` it seem like an array

Comment: @DavidWinder I know that is the strange thing -- I deleted all the code as top comment suggested. `$schedule = data returned from API`. Thus `var_export($schedule`) gave me the array as can be seen on the edit...

Comment: Not sure what is strange here, neither home or away are strings, both are arrays.

Comment: @sskoko isn't json supposed to be only a data string? Sorry Im learning would just like to know for reference.

Comment: Absolutely not. https://www.json.org/

Answer (score 1):

You are dealing with array of arrays. Try something like this:

```
  $someArray = $jsonArray
  foreach ($someArray as $key => $value) {
    echo $value["home"]["name"] . ", " . $value["away"]["name"] . "<br>";
  }
```